# PHP rename() directory acces denied on windows (xampp) despite correct chmod & file path

Tags: php, xampp

I know there are thousands of questions with similar issue, however most of them got resolved by either using chmod or they just didn't provide the full path for the new name.
I'm trying to change the cache purging behaviour of some website, because when a full purge is done, the website hangs for a good amount of time (it uses a glob & recursive function to delete each file, and there are tens of thousands of them, if not more).
The main idea is to just rename the directories used for storing cache, this way it wouldn't even take a second. The old files could be deleted later partially or whatever.
While in theory it was simple, I'm struggling for a few hours already, just because rename() is throwing me an `access denied (code 5)` error. I've already tried almost everything I could, setting the chmod of both parent directory & the directory I want to rename, fixing directory separators, nothing helped.

This is my code:

```
        // $dir = C:\xampp\htdocs\test/cache/posts.cache
        $dirToRename = substr($dir, strrpos($dir, '/')+1); // posts.cache
        $parentDir = realpath($dir. '/..') . '/'; // C:\xampp\htdocs\test/cache/

        error_log('dir '. $dir .' parentDir '. $parentDir .' dirToRename '. $dirToRename);

        rename($parentDir . $dirToRename, $parentDir . 'old_'. uniqid() . '_' .$dirToRename);
```

I tried it many ways, the way the directory separators are different is because after \test they are being added by the PHP script, this shouldn't make any difference anyway (and I've tried fixing them without any change)

What I'm getting in the log is:

> dir C:\xampp\htdocs\test/cache/posts.cache
>   parentDir C:\xampp\htdocs\test\cache/ dirName posts.cache
>   PHP Warning:
>   rename(C:\xampp\htdocs\test\cache/posts.cache,C:\xampp\htdocs\test\cache/old_5bf72ae342d2f_posts.cache):
>   Access denied. (code: 5) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\inc\cache.php on line
>   308

Obviously, the code is executed at test/inc/cache.php, so it's trying to modify a directory outside of the CWD.
Is this just a XAMPP thing, is there any way to fix this?

EDIT: I thought its about the dot in the directory name, but I can actually rename a directory that I make on my own, but not those that were generated by PHP.

Comment: Your code does not match your log output. You should always use absolute path names.

Comment: Probably this path is opened by another process.

Comment: `chmod` does not make any sense on a MS-Windows system. It changes the file system internal permissions, something MS-Windows does not even know.

Comment: The output matches, I've tried it now on a simple plain php file and a directory created by me, and it worked fine. I think it's a problem with the permissions that the php script gave to the files/directories when installing, but is it even possible on windows?

Comment: I also tried changing the cwd & restoring it with getcwd() and chdir(), no luck

Comment: Since the file name contains a period you should try putting a period at the end of the file name (to use no extension).

Comment: @CharlesEF I though its about the period, but it isnt..I just checked and when I made a directory in windows, I could rename it without any problem, it doesn't work for directories generated by PHP. I just copied one of the cache directories, renamed it to test.test and it worked, it just doesn't work for those made by php

Comment: @hazelnutek Well, I don't know what to say.  I created a test script and used 'mkdir' to create a directory with a period in the name.  I then used 'rename' to rename the directory.  No errors, directory was renamed.  I should say I use IIS on Win10.

Comment: @CharlesEF it's totally weird, it works sometimes and sometimes doesn't, like there was some magic lock on the file not being released once in a while. I can also see it happening with the original recursive function that is supposed to delete everything and the parent directory itself, sometimes it deletes just the files and leaves the directories intact, if I spam the 'reload cache' button it deletes everything at some point. Ehh, windows